# Using override init() in an XCtest class?

Tags: ios, swift, xctest

I'm wondering if there is a way to use unit when XCtesting in order to specify a constant variable that isn't torn down between separate test cases? I realize that generally best practices for unit testing are to keep the tests as self contained as possible but in my current situation it would make the tests execute a lot faster if I were able to do this and keep a constant variable between test cases.

Currently, any type of init function that I call

```
override init() {
    super.init()
}
```

Leaves me with an EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION error. If I can't use init() in XCTestCase, is there another work around that I can use?

Answer (score 7):

Try moving the variable outside of the `XCTestCase` class.

```
import XCTest

var counter = 0 // Note this is outside the class declaration

class MyTests: XCTestCase {
    override func setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        counter++
        print("Counter: \(counter)")
    }

    func testOne() {
        ...
    }

    func testTwo() {
        ...
    }

    func testThree() {
        ...
    }
}
```

This gives an output like this.

```
...
Counter: 1
...
Counter: 2
...
Counter: 3
...
```

Comment: Simple answer. Never thought of doing that. Thanks!

Comment: @helloworld345123123123 Glad it helped! If this solves your problem, could you mark the answer as correct?

Comment: Doesn't answer the question for anything by one-line definitions; more complex static setups are not possible in this way, since Swift does not have static initialization blocks.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the *class* `setUp` and `tearDown` methods for exactly this purpose.  The class `setUp` method is called once before the first test method begins and the class `tearDown` method is called once after all test methods have completed.

My understanding is that these are intended precisely for handling the kind of test-wide state you describe. Apple has some [good documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/understanding_setup_and_teardown_for_test_methods) on it.

The advantage of this approach is that the state is at least kept local to the test class, if not the individual tests.

Comment: /*!
 * @method -setUp
 * Setup method called before the invocation of each test method in the class.
 */
- (void)setUp;

Comment: setup called before every test method.

Comment: @ZaporozhchenkoAleksandr There are two separate `setUp` methods, the _instance method_ and the _class method_.  The _class_ `setUp` is called just once before the first test is called, and the _class_ `tearDown` just once after the last test has completed.

Comment: Why on earth has this comment been downvoted? It seems to be the correct answer.

@wardw I am having trouble with it, though. I have overridden the class setUp method but get a compiler error saying that it can't access instance members...

Comment: @Luke You will want to access the _instance_ `setUp()` to access instance members.  Instance members are set up/torn down between every test. Use the _class_ `setUp()` to set up initial state for the class that isn't torn down between individual instances. Class methods can't access instance members, only members of the class itself.

Comment: @Luke You may want to change the instance variables to static variables if you want to access them from a class method.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer (instead of negative score :( ) init() overriding appears to be broken for XCTestCase, but class setUp/tearDown will perform the same tasks correctly. You just have to align your thinking with each case only ever existing as one instance, use class (static) vars instead of instance vars.